# validar login con mayusculas y minusculas en php

Tags: php, login

estoy usando la clase PDO en php para realizar consultas preparadas para validar un login simple.

```
try{

    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=prueba', 'root', '');

    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $conexion->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_pass WHERE usuarios = :us AND password = :pa ";

    $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);

    //ES PARA EVITAR PROBLEMAS CON LAS COMAS O CARACTERES EXTRAÑOS investiga sobre esto
    $login = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['usu']));
    $contraseña = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['contra']));

    //Asociar las variables con los marcadores

    $resultado->bindValue(":us", $login);
    $resultado->bindValue(":pa", $contraseña);

    $resultado->execute();

    $registro = $resultado->rowCount();//Devolvera 0 o 1

    if($registro == 1){

        echo "Hay un usuario";

    }else{

        header('location: login.php');
    }


}catch(Exception $e){

    die("Error por: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

?>

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>LOGIN I</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="validar.php" method="POST">
  <label>Usuario: </label>
  <input type="text" name="usu">
  <br>
  <label>Contraseña: </label>
  <input type="password" name="contra">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

El codigo funciona muy bien solo que he notado que cuando escribo el nombre del usuario con la primera letra en mayuscula lo encuentra, pero se supone que no deberia porque tengo el nombre todo en minuscula.

Agradezco a la persona que conozca la razon de que ocurra esto gracias

Answer (score 1):

La [documentacion de mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) dice que utiliza la búsqueda sin distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas de forma predeterminada para cadenas no binarias o ciertos tipos de clasificación.

Usted ajustar cambiar este comportamiento en la definicion de la Tabla. Alternativamente, también puede ajustarlo en línea para su consulta específica. de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios_pass WHERE BINARY usuarios = :us AND password = :pa
```

Answer (score 1):

antes de pasar al parametro como variable a la consulta SQL utliza: `mb_strtoupper`

Modo de uso:

```
$param= mb_strtoupper($param, 'UTF-8');
```

Espero te funcione